# Having trouble with program arguments and Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm trying to run some scripts from a Coursera class.  The scripts do work if I manually input the data and terminate via ctrl-d.  But no matter what format I give to program arguments or place the text file, IntelliJ ignores the argument.  It doesn't seem to be at all trying to access the file - I would have expected at least an error if something was wrong in the argument box but the app just runs waiting for input.

I've tried....

1) Placing the file in an "input" folder and setting the program argument to be...

./input/tinyUF.txt

2) I'm pretty sure I tried every possible folder location for the file within the path project and then using the argument...

tinyUF.txt
and "< tinyUF.txt"

3) I tried the full Windows path as the argument as well.

Nothing helps or seems to actually make IntelliJ do anything.  Anyone know what I might not be doing correctly?

[image: Config]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not supported in IntelliJ Idea yet. You can find issue [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-88717).

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't expect that to be the answer but thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove the path from program arguments and enable check mark (Redirect input from) option in a configuration and add the file path including file name in it.

PS - I have tried it in IDEA 2019.2 (Community edition).